# How to view memory usage in eclipse (beginner)

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, lwjgl

I have been working on a game in java using eclipse for a few months now and I have been trying to figure out how to view the memory usage and what is using the most memory.  Can anyone please give me a step by step answer on how I would go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried ? What resources did you read ? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 44):

In eclipse you can try
Window --> Preferences --> General --> "Show heap status" checkbox

Answer (score 5):

You can use a good monitoring tool like [VisualVM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8n7Bg7-A4I).